# CSS to center img horizontally and vertically without resizing

Tags: html, css, image

I have code something like this:

```
<div class='image-holder' style='width:128px; height:128px'>
    <img class='thumbnail' src='image1.png'>
</div>
```

The actual size of .thumbnail is unknown, and can potentially be not an exact square.

So what I am trying to do is not change the dimensions of the image (.thumbnail) at all, but instead show just the center (both horizontally and vertically) of the image inside the .image-holder element.

For example, if the image (.thumbnail) was 256x256, the inner 128x128 section of the image should appear inside .image-holder.

I am open to using an actual img element, or, using background-image for the div. I have experimented with both with no success.

I am fairly certain I can write some javascript to do the work if necessary, but I was looking to see if there is a pure CSS solution before I go down that road.

Comment: object-fit: cover; css comes into mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `background-image` for this. Just remove the default repeating from it, and set the `background-position: center;`

See it here:

```css
.image-holder {
  width:128px;
  height:128px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#holder-1 {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150');
}

#holder-2 {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/100x100');
}
```

```html
<div id="holder-1" class='image-holder'></div>
<div id="holder-2" class='image-holder'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly for my scenario.